# Azure logic apps to return multiple response

Tags: response, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a azure logic app. This logic app should return first response with status code 202 accepted, send it back with a id and then process remaining workflow and then return 200 status code with final response. I am new to logic apps. Can this be achieved in azure logic apps, Please guide.
Thanks.

Comment: if you use http trigger, by default it returns a 202 then you could use a REST connector to call back an api.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, your Logic App has a "**When a HTTP request is received**" trigger.

If you add a "**Response**" action and trigger the Logic App, it will run synchronously and return what you call the "final response" to the caller.

If you enable the `Asynchronous Response` setting in your "Response" action and trigger the Logic App again, it will work as you expect it to:

- when the Logic App is triggered it will return 202 immediately, and the `Location` header of the response will contain a URL.
- when you send a GET request to the URL from the response's `Location` header, it will return either 202 (and the response body will show that the Logic App is still running) or 200 (if that's the status code you selected in your "Response" action) with the final response, as expected.

Comment: I'm in the same situation except I want it to return 200 the first time and then finish the workflow. Possible or does it need a queue and some queue monitoring process? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres?tabs=consumption#add-a-response-action) notes the Response action must be last "In a Standard logic app _stateless_ workflow" implying it may be allowed if stateful...

Comment: That's right. If you add the "Response" action to the end of the workflow not enabling the 'Asynchronous Response' setting, and trigger the Logic App, it will run synchronously, return the 200 response, and finish the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

That's how usually a logic app works. There is nothing like the whole logic app returning with an ID but it is the connector in the Logic app that returns the values and the flow is continued within the logic app.

The whole Logic App is a workflow which is a collection of connectors that works according to our requirement

For more information, you can refer to it from [Azure Logic Apps documentation | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/) and [Introduction to Azure Logic Apps - Learn | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/intro-to-logic-apps/).