# Logic Apps Ignoring Async Setting for Response

Tags: azure-logic-apps

[image]I built a Power Automate, HTTP-triggered flow that makes a Response at the beginning of the flow, followed by several lengthy actions.  The Response returns immediately.

I have tried to recreate that flow in Logic Apps.  However, even if I move the Response action to appear immediately after the HTTP trigger and configure the Response to be async, the Response does not return until the entire flow has completed.

Posts like [Azure logic apps to return multiple response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69083005/azure-logic-apps-to-return-multiple-response) and articles like https://www.serverless360.com/blog/logic-app-best-practices-tips-and-tricks-26-call-asynchronous-child-logic-apps state that you can achieve an immediate response with the async setting.  Is there anything I may be overlooking to get this to work?

Comment: Sounds weird, can you share an image of your flow?

Comment: done.  it's hard to fit more of the flow in an image.

Comment: I've never needed to flick the async flag on, have you tried it with it off?

Comment: yes.  i tried it without.  See my answer below. The workflow needs to be stateful for the async flag to work.

Answer (score 0):

My workflow was stateless.  it appears that a async response only works if the workflow is stateful, likely because the flow could have a longer life.

my only issue now is that there does not appear to be a way to convert an existing flow from stateless to stateful.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and ASYNC is working correctly for me as below:

The logic app design:

[image]

Output:

[image]

For this to work I have used stateful.